# How to connect splash screen with .gif animation file?

Tags: java, android, animation, splash-screen

I have developed an app that plays a music when the user presses on button. And I have also developed a splash screen along with the app and it did work with the app. However, I want to modify my app so that splash screen plays gif file instead of regular image. When I tried .gif file by creating new project  it did worked. I used movie class for that. I tried intent for my splash screen so that it calls gif.java file. But it did not worked. It just showed me the distorted image of my gif file. And than It said 
"Your APP HAS CRASHED".  My main java, splash screen and gif .java files  and manifest.xml are the following.

Main Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        private MediaPlayer mp;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          setContentView(new MYGIFView (this));
          setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(this);
          findViewById(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
          findViewById(R.id.button_3).setOnClickListener(this);
       }
       public void onClick(View v) {   
           int resId=1;

       // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
          if (mp != null) {   
              mp.release(); 
          } 

          switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.button_1: resId = R.raw.button_1; break;
          case R.id.button_2: resId = R.raw.button_2; break;
          case R.id.button_3:
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
             return;

          }

       // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
          mp.start();
       }
    }
```

Splash Screen. java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MYGIFView.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

MYGIF.java

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.view.View;

class MYGIFView extends View{

Movie movie,movie1;
InputStream is=null,is1=null;
long moviestart;
public MYGIFView(Context context) {
super(context);




is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.th_welcome);
movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
super.onDraw(canvas);
long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
System.out.println("now="+now);
if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
moviestart = now;

}
System.out.println("\tmoviestart="+moviestart);
int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration()) ;
System.out.println("time="+relTime+"\treltime="+movie.duration());
movie.setTime(relTime);
canvas.scale(3.50f, 3.50f);
movie.draw(canvas,20,20);
this.invalidate();
}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >       
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat error

```
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 

{.MYGIFView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at com.$1.run(SplashScreen.java:29)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-24 17:04:36.332: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you suggesting me to change the name of my class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is starting a new "activity" with the MYGIFView class.
It seem that it should be an activity, not a View.

Think just need to had

```
setContentView(new MYGIFView(this));
```

In the onCreate of the SplashActivity, before the handler declaration.
and remove it in the onCreate of the MainActivity (seem it's a mistake here).

And then replace `MyGIFView.class` with `MainActivity.class` in the post delayed Handler :

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
```

And also need to remove the `LAUNCHER` and `MAIN` param of the manifest for the main activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Edited** : erata SecondActivity -> MainActivity