# Getting Null Pointer Exception while implementing Gif image in SplashScreen

Tags: android, image, gif, splash-screen

I have tried to use Gif image into my SplashScreen. When I run it I get the following error and an app is crashed.

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference**

Please help me to fix it. Your answer is more appreciated.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MYGIFView(context));
        context=this;
    }

    public class MYGIFView extends View {
        Movie movie, movie1;
        InputStream is = null, is1 = null;
        long moviestart;

        public MYGIFView(Context con) {
            super(con);           // ERROR IN THIS LINE
            con=context;
            is = con.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.splash_screen);
            movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            System.out.println("now=" + now);
            if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
                moviestart = now;
            }
            System.out.println("\tmoviestart=" + moviestart);
            int relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
            System.out.println("time=" + relTime + "\treltime=" + movie.duration());
            movie.setTime(relTime);
            movie.draw(canvas, this.getWidth() / 2 - 20, this.getHeight() / 2 - 40);
            this.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch sequence of this two statements.
1.        context=this;
2.setContentView(new MYGIFView(context));

Comment: Ya tried.But still app is crashed.

Comment: Get line number from logcat. Start debugging. Find which object is not assigned

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
setContentView(new MYGIFView(context));
context=this;
```

**Do**

```
setContentView(new MYGIFView(SplashScreen.this));
```

**Edit**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference
>
> ```
> context is not passing
> ```

**NullPointerException** is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference, having the null value.

You can try with

```
 context=this;
 setContentView(new MYGIFView(context));
```

**Missing**

```
setContentView(R.layout.Your_Activity_xml); // Missing
setContentView(new MYGIFView(this));
```

Try with this

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MYGIFView(SplashScreen.this));

}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: `setContentView(new MYGIFView(this));`

Comment: @ParamaSudha Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939745/how-to-connect-splash-screen-with-gif-animation-file

Comment: Ya tried.But the app is crashed again.

Comment: @ParamaSudha Same error ?

Comment: E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/17463/oom_score_adj; errno=2
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 17493 (lobe.restaurant)
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Comment: While I run this again, logcat shows this.

Comment: @ParamaSudha what is `Invalid thumbnail dimensions:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105422/discussion-between-parama-sudha-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: I m sorry.What does it in mean?

Comment: My Gif image size is 1080 X 1920

Comment: @ParamaSudha I guess its too large .

Comment: Okay.Thank you.Let me try to resize it.

Comment: @ParamaSudha make sure You have add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

Comment: @ParamaSudha Any success ?

Comment: Didnt get any error.But corner is filled with black & view is not fine as original & shows with out animation.

Comment: @ParamaSudha Thats another case .